# Mass redirects urls in Wordpress removing a word in the end, how?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hy guys, due to an Elementor Pro bug, after an update (old one) all my articles blog post was also indexed with my work telephone number in the end of the url like this:

https://site.it/blog-post/telephonenumber/

All these bad urls are now present in the coverage section of my Google Search Control and i want to sanitize this situation for my Seo. How can i mass redirect or deindex or remove this bad url via htaccess or WP Redirection plugin?

I would like to let all my blog post url WITH /telephonenumber/ in the end to be redirected to my same blog post with the normal url:

from https://site.it/blog-post/telephonenumber/

to https://site.it/blog-post/

Thanks!

PS: i had the same issue with the /amp/ in the end of the url and I "solved" with this code:

````
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
# END Redirect from AMP to non-AMP path```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in your htaccess to redirect  your URLs with phone number string at the end .

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/[0-9]+/?$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to place this redirect at the top of your htaccess or before other rules in your htaccess.